# Schedule SMS in Message+ on Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s7, verizon, message+

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7.  It comes with Message+ which I would like to keep using.  How do I schedule a text message to be sent later?  In other words, I would like to delay send the SMS.

Answer (score 1):

The default Samsung message app has a built in delay feature. Type the message you want to delay, then touch the menu bars or dots. Find the option that says "schedule", then follow thru prompts.